# Advanced Excel Help - Lookup Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've tried index match and xlookup to no avail.  I don't use offset much, and not sure if that's the fix either.  I can't share the spreadsheet because it has sensitive data, but I'll provide the screen shots and the formula that is currently used here.

[image]
[image]

```
=XLOOKUP(BI$2,answers!$E:$E,XLOOKUP(testers!$A543,answers!$B:$B,answers!$F:$F))
```

excel-lookup-formula
testers worksheet:
I'm trying to pull the 'response' provided by user ID (col A) to a specific question (Row 2)

excel-lookup-table
answers worksheet
User IDs (Col B)
Question # (Col E)
Response (Col F)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=INDEX(answers!$F:$F,MATCH(1,($A543=answers!$B:$B)*(BI$2=answers!$E:$E),0))`

For Excel versions prior to Office 365 this needs confirmed with `ctrl+shift+enter`